# In spring framework, How to pass the parameters to another controler

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Is it possible to pass parameters from one to another Controller?

@Controller
public class ICentraSrcCtrlLoginController {

@PostMapping("/iCentraSrcCtrlLogin")
    public ModelAndView  iCentraSrcCtrlLoginSubmit(@ModelAttribute ICentraSrcCtrlLogin inp, Model model) {

```
ICentraSrcCtrl iCentraSrcCtrl = new ICentraSrcCtrl();

Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();

myModel.put("iCentraPassWd", inp.getiCentraPassWd());
myModel.put("UsrPassWd", inp.getUsrPassWd());
myModel.put("iCentraSrcCtrl", iCentraSrcCtrl);

return new ModelAndView("redirect:/iCentraSrcCtrl", "iCentraSrcCtrl", myModel);


}
```

}

@Controller
public class ICentraSrcCtrlController {

@GetMapping("/iCentraSrcCtrl")
    public String iCentraSrcCtrlForm(Model model) {

```
logger.info("iCentraSrcCtrlForm");

Map<String, Object> myModel = model.asMap();
logger.info("iCentraPassWd size: " + myModel.size());
logger.info("iCentraPassWd: " + new Boolean(myModel.containsKey("iCentraPassWd")).toString());
```

}
}
The output of logger:

ICentraSrcCtrlController                 : iCentraPassWd size: 0
ICentraSrcCtrlController                 : iCentraPassWd: false

Answer (score 0):

Used RedirectView to pass values to the new controller.

```
ra.addFlashAttribute("iCentraPassWd", inp.getiCentraPassWd());
ra.addFlashAttribute("UsrPassWd", inp.getUsrPassWd());
RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
redirectView.setContextRelative(true);
redirectView.setUrl("/iCentraSrcCtrl");
return redirectView;
```